# XSLT display ALL XML tag contents

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes

I am new to using XSLT.  I want to display all of the information in an xml tag in my xsl formatted page.  I have tried using local-name, name, etc and none give me the result I want.

Example:

```
 <step bar="a" bee="localhost" Id="1" Rt="00:00:03" Name="hello">Pass</step>
```

I would like to be able to print out all of the information (`bar="a"`, `bee="localhost"`) etc as well as the value of `<step>` Pass.

How can I do this with xsl?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you just want the values of the attributes, or the names as well? (`bar="a"` vs `a`)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return just the values, you could use the XPath `//text()|@*`.

If you want the attribute/element names along with the values, you could use this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name(parent::*),'> ',.,'&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),'=&#x22;',.,'&#x22;&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With your input, it will produce this output:

```
bar="a"
bee="localhost"
Id="1"
Rt="00:00:03"
Name="hello"
<step> Pass
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:for-each select="attribute::*">   
  <xsl:value-of select="text()" />   
  <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />   
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:value-of select="text()" />   
<xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
```

Comment: xsl that is - but it could be - if I changed the namespace-prefix :)

Comment: I knew that, but the OP said that they were new to XSLT and I was just pointing out the typo. It might confuse the OP if they try to use your answer. Also, the `value-of` elements aren't closed; that would probably cause confusion as well. Kind of surprised that this answer got an upvote in this condition. :-)

Comment: damn did not se that - you know when it colors your code, sometime you miss the discipline ...oopsss