# XElement get start Tag string

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml, xelement

Is possible to get the start tag string of an XElement?

For example, if i have an xml element like this

```
<Product Id="101" Name="Product 1">
    <Images>
        // ..
    </Images>
    <Description>
        // ..
    </Description>
</Product>
```

i want to get only the start tag:

```
<Product Id="101" Name="Product 1">
```

I use this for validation feedback purposes.

Comment: what are you using to traverse the XML document:
XML reader, XPathNavigator .... ?

Comment: XDocument is how you are storing the Data in memory, but how are you reading the tags one by one in the document, or you didn't do that yet ?

Comment: To read elements i do something like this: (XDocument) `xDocument.Element("root").Elements("Product")`, which gives me a list of `XElement` objects

Comment: This is a possible duplicate for your question:
[using XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518717/xslt-display-all-xml-tag-contents)

Comment: I was hoping for an easier workaround

Answer (score 0):

use query like

```
 XElement xele = XElement.Load("xmlfilename");
 XNamespace _XNamespace = XNamespace.Get("namespace url");
 IEnumerable<XElement> ProductAttribute = from ele in xele .Descendants(_XNamespace + "Product ")
                                          where ele.Attribute("Id").Value =="101" && ele.Attribute("Name") == "Product 1"
                                          select ele;
```

Hope it will work for you