# XSLT String length from beginning of document

Tags: xhtml, xslt-2.0

I have this XSLT to split a 25 MB XHTML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="html/body"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" 
        group-starting-with="*[position()=1 or @class='toc']">            
        <xsl:if test="count(current-group()[self::*]) &gt; 0 ">
          <xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('/home/t',position(),'.xml' )"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:result-document 
                 indent="yes" method="xml" href="$filename}">                    
                <html>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="/html/@*"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/html/node()">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="not(self::body)">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:copy>
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                                </xsl:copy>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </html>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It currently works at splitting up the file when it finds a `@toc`. I need to alter this to be sensitive to *size* of the output file, as opposed to breaking at the `@toc`.

Desired end state: I want the result document to be about 500KB. I suppose `position()` might be the best way to regulate the split points?? I tried various `string-length()` approaches--I could not get one to work. Also, I think white space may be an issue.

By my calculations with these documents, splitting the file at a `<p class="i0">` found *at or near* every `150th position` increment should reliably give me the filesize I need.

I guess the best way to get there is to change this:

```
group-starting-with="*[position()=1 or @class='toc']"
```

So far I have not succeeded in anything I have changed it to. Thoughts?

**UPDATE:** I'm not ready to say this is answered, because someone may have a better idea. But right now I'm using `group-starting-with="body/*[position()=1 or position() mod 350 = 0]"` with some success. It is testing well.
**UPDATE 2:** The `group-starting-with="body/*[position()=1 or position() mod 350 = 0]"` is not working well. Problem is that it is the position within the for-each-loop, not the overall file.

Comment: When your XML is loaded into memory it is converted into a DOM tree.  The serialized (text) representation doesn't exist at that point so you'd have to account for tag name and attribute name length.  I'm not sure XSLT is the right tool for this job.  If I were doing this I'd consider a JAXP stream-based implementation.  Maybe if you described your problem at a higher level we could suggest alternatives.

Comment: If your suggested split criterion (`<p class="i0">`) occurs at a lower level than `<toc>` (which I assume) the question is how you would like to handle `<toc>`'s being split up across files?

Comment: Marcus...I run two more templates after this one. One recurses through all the XML files in the directory and collects @ID and Filename associations. The next template reconnects the broken <a> ID's with their new filenames.

Comment: Jim...I believe you are correct. XSLT probably isn't the perfect tool for the job. But I'm trying to focus on XSLT so I can get better at it. I don't know Java at all. It strikes me that xquery may be good for this task--but I don't want to pick that up quite just yet.

Comment: Part of getting better at XSLT (or programming in general) is realising when a specific language or tool won't work. Many languages besides Java can also read and run XSLT if required. Perhaps on of those would help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT display ALL XML tag contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518717/xslt-display-all-xml-tag-contents)

Comment: Not a dupe Paul. I needed to maintain a running total of document size in an attribute, that's different from rendering text. The successful solution ended up being an xslt 3.0 accumulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The successful solution ended up being an xslt 3.0 accumulator.

As an alternative:

> Dmitiri Novatchev solution for XSLT 1.0:
>
> This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="vResult">
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:variable>

   Length of output is: <xsl:text/>
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(string-length($vResult), '&#xA;')"/>

   <xsl:if test="string-length($vResult) &lt;= 1800">
 <xsl:copy-of select="$vResult"/>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> when applied on this source.xml:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

> produces the wanted result:
>
> Length of output is: 51
>       
>         01
>         02
>         03
>         04
>         05
>         06
>         07
>         08
>         09
>         10

**References**

- [XSLT FAQ: WML and HDML - Measuring the size of the output file, in bytes](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N8343.html#d11543e159)
- [XSLT 3.0: Accumulator Function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dt-accumulator-function)
- [Utilizing new capabilities of XML languages to verify integrity constraints](http://www.balisage.net/Proceedings/vol8/html/Maly01/BalisageVol8-Maly01.html#sec-iterator)
- [A Functional Tokenizer (Was: Re: Looping over a CSV in XSL)](http://www.sourceware.org/ml/xsl-list/2001-11/msg00901.html)
- [XSL Techniques](http://usingxml.com/Transforms/XslTechniques)
- [FXSL:sumTree](http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/articles/FuncProg/3.html#sumTree)